# Using uvm_reg_hw_reset_seq

Tags: uvm

I'm newbie in UVM. Now I am building the Register Model for my project. I see UVM support `uvm_reg_hw_reset_seq` for supporting testing reg-model's `reset-process`.
How can I use it?

Comment: Please make an attempt and get back to us with code and problems you faced. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in following order to execute the sequence.

- Create an object through `type_id::create` method.
- Initialise `<instance>.model` handle to your actual register model handle.
- Start the sequence object on sequencer.

For more information, refer UVM Cookbook - https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/uvm

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved my problem now.  Actually, I had created and connect model for uvm_reg_hw_reset_seq, but when I call start for it, I don't know what sequencer I must input for it. I solve this by inputting "null" for it.

Comment: Your welcome. If above post was helpful to you, then please mark it as answer to close this question.